# RPi Zero W (Jessie) ffmpeg illegal instruction

Tags: raspbian-jessie, home-automation, ffmpeg

Trying to build and install ffmpeg with hardware encoder and rtsp streaming enabled.  Attempted to follow instructions here: (https://github.com/KhaosT/homebridge-camera-ffmpeg/wiki/Raspberry-PI) but running ffmpeg command to test installation immediately results in "Illegal instructions".

Copying code from website here:

```
# install build tools
sudo apt-get install pkg-config autoconf automake libtool libx264-dev

# download and build fdk-aac
git clone https://github.com/mstorsjo/fdk-aac.git
cd fdk-aac
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared --enable-static
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
cd ..

# download and build ffmpeg
git clone https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.git
cd FFmpeg
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --arch=armel --target-os=linux --enable-omx-rpi --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-mmal --enable-libx264 --enable-decoder=h264 --enable-network --enable-protocol=tcp --enable-demuxer=rtsp
make
sudo make install
```

Tried installing it this way (https://superuser.com/a/1082860), which didn't work -- resulted in "can't find command".

Tried this way (https://superuser.com/a/1069053), and couldn't even get past configure.

I'm at a complete lost.  I figured I probably need instructions for cleaning up the mess I probably created from my attempts as well as how to actually get ffmpeg either compiled or downloaded for use with homebridge-camera-ffmpeg.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I also installed libfdk-aac-dev from deb-multimedia's list because the ffmpeg's .configure still complained about missing fdk-aac after the fdk-aac build. Is the deb-multimedia list installation the cause of my issues and did I officially put my RPi in hell? (see: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1055179)

Comment: This may be of use https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=199775

Comment: as far as I can see, the stock standard ffmpeg has RTSP enabled (I could be wrong about this), but `omx-rpi` and `mmal` are **definitely** present  - also, the only reason to use *fdk-aac* is if you want to use HE-AAC, otherwise the *builtin* aac codec is on par with fdk-aac for 128kbit audio - and as SOON as I hit post, I see the magic word `jessie` in the title ...

Comment: @JaromandaX Is `Jessie` the magic word that breaks all assumptions? Would upgrading to `Stretch` help things?  I've read that stock ffmpeg are compiled for armv7 instead of armv6 that's in the Zero, thus the illegal instructions.  Sorry, still a noob at this.

Comment: it's just that as I said, ffmpeg in stretch probably has what you want without needing to compile

Comment: @JaromandaX Great, thanks,  I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Just to report back for future reference: upgrading to `Stretch` by itself didn't fix it.  Ended up with a format and reinstall to clear the `illegal instruction`.  Ffmpeg was in fact installed with `Stretch` though with the mentioned options enabled.  Thanks again for your help.